# no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class “c('double', 'numeric')” when using `count`

Tags: r

using this below code I am trying to weight each year in each iteration based on column "weight".
using `wtd.table` I have the following code:

```
wtd.table(result$`it 1`$`year 5`$age,result$`it 1`$`year 5`$gender ,result$`it 1`$`year 5`$district, weights =result$`it 1`$`year 5`$weight )
```

This output only provides age and gender weighted. It does not also include district. based on some purposes I have used `count(var1, var2, var3 , wt = wt)` like this:

```
count(result$`it 1`$`year 5`$age,result$`it 1`$`year 5`$gender,
result$`it 1`$`year 5`$age,
wt = result$`it 1`$`year 5`$weight)
```

but I got this error: Error in UseMethod("count") :
no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')".
how can I fix that?

here is my code:

```
iter1 <- list(year1 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13), district=c(1,2,3,4),gender=c(1,2,2,1)
,weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1)),
year2 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13), district=c(1,2,3,4),gender=c(1,2,2,1),weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1)))

iter2 <- list(year1 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13), district=c(1,2,3,4),gender=c(2,2,1,1)
,weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1)),
year2 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13), district=c(1,2,3,4),gender=c(2,2,1,1),weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1)))

df <- list(iter1 = iter1, iter2 = iter2)
```

my expected output is like df1

df1<-

```
district   age    gender  freq   
1          10       1     12.2
1          11       1      0.0 
1          12       1      0.0
1          13       1     10.1
1          10       2      0.0
1          11       2     11.3
1          12       2     11.2
1          13       2      0.0
```

Comment: where is our code with count? What is your expected results?

Comment: @ Onyambu please see my output.

Comment: and how do you get that output?

Comment: it is just my expected output

Comment: yes what is the logic to get there?

Comment: for each **district**  I would have frequency table of gender and age

Comment: `map_dfr(df, bind_rows, .id='grp')%>%complete(grp,district,gender,age, fill = list(weight=0))%>%distinct()`??

Comment: I got this error :could not find function "complete", also why weight should be 0??

Comment: use `library(tidyverse)`. Its not that weight is 0. The missing weight is set to 0. I do not know exactly what you are doing. You never explained  how you obtained your expected output

Comment: thanks. as shown in my code, each year has a column named "weight" I just want weight each year based this column in such a way that for each district I would have a data frame like df1.

Comment: try running `map_dfr(df, bind_rows)`

Comment: sorry but your explanation is vague. this question was asked 1 hour ago. you wold rather consider asking the question again but this time elaborate on what you exactly need. people tend to answer recently asked questions.

Comment: thanks @Onyambu. can you explain what part of my question is vague?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the nested list in one dataframe and use `complete` to fill the missing observations of `weight` with 0.

```
library(tidyverse)

map_df(df, ~bind_rows(.x, .id = 'year'), .id = 'iter') %>%
  complete(iter, year, age, district, gender, fill = list(weight = 0))
```

Comment: thanks @ Ronak shah. what if I want to have just specific year and iteration?

Comment: You can `filter` the values that you want. `%>% filter(iter == 'iter1', year == 'year1')`

Comment: I got this error no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: @mehmo You need to add `filter` step after `complete`. I don't get any such error when using `map_df(df, ~bind_rows(.x, .id = 'year'), .id = 'iter') %>% complete(iter, year, age, district, gender, fill = list(weight = 0)) %>% dplyr::filter(iter == 'iter1', year == 'year1')`

Comment: actually it works but produces 0 observation

Comment: @mehmo Using my above code (in comment) on the data that you have shared I get 32 rows.

Comment: thank you so much and one more question, can I have mean of iterations in a data frame and  in different confidence interval?

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand your question but mean of iterations can be calculated using `group_by` and `mean`. This post might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group